# How Get Products URL's in magento 2.2

Tags: product, magento2.2, product-attribute

I want to get products URL's using product collection,I have tried many links from searching browser,please help me with appropriate file path this is my module catalog import export code to get URL's in export.

```
protected function loadCollection(): array
{
    $data = [];

    $collection = $this->_getEntityCollection();
    foreach (array_keys($this->_storeIdToCode) as $storeId) {
        $collection->setStoreId($storeId);
        foreach ($collection as $itemId => $item) {
            $data[$itemId][$storeId] = $item;
        }
        $collection->clear();
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: `$product->getProductUrl()` if you have product object

Comment: @shoaib from where i get product object can u specify the file path..?

Comment: where do you want product url? on which file you are working on?

Comment: i am working on catalog import export module under product file to get products Url's when i export the products url's should come in export sheet

Comment: in that file, is there any foreach loop on product collection? if yes, then please share your code in question

Comment: @ShoaibMunir if other way to get product url's without export sheet ..?

Comment: in foreach loop try `$item->getProductUrl()`

Comment: To get the product object, $_product = $block->getProduct();
To get the Product Url Key Use, echo $_product->getUrlKey();

Answer (score 1):

> Run this file on your magento root Directory

```
<?php 
ob_start();
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productCollection */
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
/** Apply filters here */
$collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->load();
$collection->addUrlRewrite();
foreach ($collection as $product){
     echo $product->getProductUrl().'<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: effective but generating given links  
https://www.juliancharles.co.uk/catalog/product/view/id/160/SID=bbad6c1ba8b1d932f3e8ea499ec9e06

generating few links correct

https://www.juliancharles.co.uk/goose-feather-down-pillow-medium-support-single/?SID=bbad6c1ba8b1bd932f3e8ea499ec9e06

Comment: add `$collection->addUrlRewrite();` and Do reindexing it working fore me

Comment: also records are not complete 25% of total records...?
any suggestion to change ...?

Comment: `Display Out of Stock Product` to `yes` in `Config >> catalog >> inventory >> Stock Option`

Comment: some URLs are not generating properly still
any idea